How to fix invisible expanded widget?
I have a row with only flexible expanded widgets:
Row(child:[
   Expanded(flex:1, child: greenChild),  //Expanded -> Flexible, same result
   Expanded(flex:3, child: redChild),
]);

What I see is:  
... the green child is black (not green) --- it is actually unpainted and changes from white/black when dragging the window between desktops (This is a linux target).
Why is this? How can I fix it?
AFAICT, no combination of Expanded/Flexible works:
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  Widget red = Container(color: Colors.red);
  Widget green = Container(color: Colors.green);
  Widget child = Row(
    children: [
      // Nope:
      Expanded( flex: 1, child: green,),
      Expanded(flex: 3, child: red),

      // // Nope:
      // Flexible( flex: 1, child: green,),
      // Expanded(flex: 3, child: red),
      //
      // // Nope:
      // Expanded( flex: 1, child: green,),
      // Flexible(flex: 3, child: red),
      //
      // // Nope:
      // Flexible( flex: 1, child: green,),
      // Flexible(flex: 3, child: red),
    ],
  );

  return runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      // Does not help
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder: (context) => child),
      )));

}


The Widget inspector shows that the left column data has a defined size:

If I remove red container, I get the result below (yellow container). Why is this not a fixed size? Is this related to the first problem?
  Widget child = Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.yellow)
        ),
      ),
      // Expanded(
      //     flex: 3,
      //     child: Container(
      //       color: Colors.red,
      //     )),
    ],
  );



You have an Expanded widget inside a Row widget. The Expanded widget will cause the child to expand across all available space in a row regardless of fixed or specified width. Remove the Expanded widget to stop it from expanding across all available space. As for the color, I don't see any color changes when re-producing your code. Can you share the full code for greenChild?

What 's the purpose of Expanded(flex: ... ) then?  Also, I get the same result for any combination of Flex/Explanded in the column -- the left column is never painted.
There was already a working example - I've updated it.

The flex only sets a ratio between 2 or more Expanded/Flexible widgets. If there is only 1 Expanded widget, the flex won't do anything

I copy pasted your code in dartpad and I don't see any issue with the color. So the cause of the problem is not from the coding side unless there's more to your code. See demo here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=2535a03b2c758d614b59b0fd3b5e65f2

As I said, it fails with any combination of Expanded/Flexible.
Should none of them work? (The documentation doesn't suggest that the flex value is relative to the entire parent and only a single flex child is allowed.
Expanded docs: "If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor." It does so that, but then fails to paint one of the children.

Its works for me in Web, but fails for Linux builds.

The behavior was a flutter bug (now fixed in master branch).
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/151021
